# Вычисление CRC32 суммы каждой строки файла

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость вычисления контрольной суммы на каждую линию текстового файла. Результат необходимо записать в отдельный файл.

Например есть файл data.txt которой содержит следующий текст:

```
Кресло 
Тумба приставная
Портофино
Тумба под аппаратуру
Бумага цветная
Помпа для воды
Корзина для мусора
Линейка металлическая 
Точилка
```

Необходимо создать рядом файл data_crc32 который будет содержать на каждой строке соответствующую контрольную сумму crc32:

```
38bb8239
27c01629
9446ea58
946f4d36
7b6976f8
575f06ea
eb3838f1
e65783ac
e432918b
```

Хотелось бы реализовать данное решение на php

Comment: И что помешало вам ввести в гугле два запроса "php file" и "php crc32" этих двух функций и чуть чуть логики уже позволят решить задачу

Comment: Не понимаю - что помешало коментаторам пройти мимо, если вопрос не понравился? Этот сервис существует для того, чтобы одни люди могли помочь другим.

Comment: @Miron, небольшое уточнение для правильного восприятия цели существования данного сайта: 1. это база знаний для программистов. 2. одна и та же пара «вопрос+ответ(ы)» благодаря поисковикам может помочь десяткам/сотням/тысячам/и т.д. программистов. 3. а факт конкретной помощи конкретнгму вопрошающему со стороны конкретного отвечающего — это лишь *единичный* частный случай, так сказать, «приятный побочный эффект». // изложенное никак не отменяет абсолютную бесполезность (для тех самых десятков/сотен/тысяч программистов), например, первого комментария (от Владимира Мартьянова).

Answer (score 1):

Ниже реализация и подробные комментарии, какая строка что делает. Если Вы хотите освоить PHP, то можете подробно посмотреть информацию на русском языке по каждой функции, добавив её название после адреса сайта, например так: http://php.net/fopen

```
<?php
$fp_read = fopen("data.txt", "r"); // Открываем файл на чтение
$fp_write = fopen("data_crc32.txt", "w"); // Открываем файл на запись
while (!feof($fp_read)) {
    $data = fgets($fp_read, 4096); // Получаем строку из файла data.txt
    $data = trim($data); // Очищаем строку от лишних пробелов и символов перевода коретки: \n, \r\n, etc
    $data = crc32($data); // Получаем crc32
    $data = $data."\n"; // Добавляем символ перевода каретки или \r\n - если Виндовс
    fwrite($fp_write, $data); // Записываем результат в файл data_crc32.txt - построчно
    //echo crc32($buffer).' ';
}
fclose($fp_read); // Закрываем файл
fclose($fp_write); // Закрываем файл
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответы всем. Давно программировал на php простенькие программы для себя. Уже более 5 лет не занимался им - всё позабылось!